# add_image_size in Wordpress - fixed width & 100% height

Tags: wordpress, image, height, width

I would like to add an image size to Wordpress where the width is fixed (516px) and the height is 100% (no crop). What is actually the right method to do this ?

would the function below is the right way to achieve that ?

```
add_image_size('my_image', 516, 9999, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,

I have found the answer:

**add_image_size('my_image', 516, false);**